# working of OnConfigurationChanged() in MonoDroid

Tags: c#, android, monodevelop, xamarin.android, onconfigurationchanged

I'm new to android development and I've been working on android through java(eclipse) till now but now I'm switching to `Mono for Android` which uses C#.

In java on orientation changed, I've used following code snippet :

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else{
             Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

When trying to do the same in C# in `Mono for Android`, I tried this

```
 public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
        {
            base.OnConfigurationChanged (newConfig);
            if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)  
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "landscape",ToastLength.Long).Show();
            } 
            else /* if (orientation == 0) */
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "portrait", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
```

**but `Android.Content.Res.Configuration` doesn't have any attribute with value 'ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`** when I try to use following statement

```
if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
```

What might be the solution? Any other option available?

Any help appreciated !

Comment: Can you specify "doesn't accept the statement"? Do you get an error message? What is it?

Comment: Sorry. I guess I was bit unclear. **I meant `Android.Content.Res.Configuration` doesn't have any attribute with value 'ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use:

```
Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape
```

[API reference - enum](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Content.Res.Orientation)

[API refenence - Configuration](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.Content.Res.Configuration.Orientation)